# Cannot apply matrix to loaded model using three.js

Tags: three.js, webgl

I would like to load a model using three.js and then apply a transformation matrix on top of it. This is the code I am using:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loader.addEventListener('load', function (event)
{
    var object = event.content;
    object.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
    object.applyMatrix(object_accumulated_matrix);
    scene.add(object);
},
{
    useWorker: true
});

// should check if ".mtl" file exists but there is no access to the filesystem
loader.load(dir_file_name + ".obj", dir_file_name + ".mtl");
```

and these are the contents of the object_accumulated_matrix variable:

```
({elements:{0:1, 1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:1, 6:0, 7:322, 8:0, 9:0, 10:1, 11:0, 12:0, 13:0, 14:0, 15:1}})
```

There is a 322 translation value on the Y-axis but I can not seem to get it to work. I have also tried:

```
object.matrix.copy(object_accumulated_matrix);
```

but that did not work either.

I would appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `object_accumulated_matrix` is transposed.

You can also try

```
object.geometry.applyMatrix( object_accumulated_matrix );
```

which will modify the geometry itself.

Comment: I would have never thought that it is transposed as it is the result of a matrix.compose(transl, rot, scale) and I assumed this operation creates the matrices as required.

Comment: Also can you elaborate more on the difference between object.applyMatrix and object.geometry.applyMatrix. It is not very clear from the documentation.

Comment: The translation component of the matrix is in the right-hand column. object.applyMatrix sets the object's position, rotation, and scale vectors; geometry.applyMatrix transforms the geometry vertices. object.matrix is the object's transformation matrix. Please remember to "accept" answers by clicking on the check mark. If you have other questions, please make a new post.